# Grouping OneToOne Fields together in the Admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have 4 OneToOne relations to a model, and in the admin area I would like to group them so they can be edited in pairs(2 groups of 2).  Is there a way to do this similar to using fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the field order (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) and also create fieldsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) for the admin interface